# Checking if image exists - Django (1.3)

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template to display images according to some variable {{var}}.jpg
If somehow for a particular value of var, there is not corresponding image, I want to display a fallback image for aesthetic purposes.

How do I achieve this?

I have defined a static path and I'm using

```
{% load static %}

<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/{{var}}.jpg">
```

to display my images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only image url in {{var}}. Then you can simply do this:

```
{% if var %}
   <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/{{var}}.jpg"> 
{% else %}
   <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/fallback.jpg"> 
{% endif %}
```

or if there is 'image' field of {{var}} then:

```
{% if var.image %}
   <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/{{var}}.jpg"> 
{% else %}
   <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/fallback.jpg"> 
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 9):

Write a [Custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) for that.

```
{% if var|image_exists %}
   <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/{{var}}.jpg"> 
{% else %}
   <img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/fallback.jpg"> 
{% endif %}
```

`image_exists` is custom filter. There is a simple line will work for you.

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

default_storage.exists(your_image_path)
```

Comment: For those who doesn't know where the `default_storage` comes from:
`from django.core.files.storage import default_storage`

Answer (score 2):

If the variable is not an instance of an object with a picture associated to it (meaning `{{ var.image }}` would not work), but instead `{{ var }}` simply indicates the name of the static image:

Instead of using

`<img src="{% get_static_prefix %}img/{{var}}.jpg">`

do

`<div id="my_image" style="background: url({% get_static_prefix %}img/{{var}}.jpg)"></div>`

and then add a wrapping `div` with the backup image, resulting in:

```html
<div id="my_backup_image" style="background: url({% get_static_prefix %}img/backup.jpg)">
 <div id="my_image" style="background: url({% get_static_prefix %}img/{{var}}.jpg)"></div>
</div>
```

This way, both backgrounds are active, but when the inner fails only the outer is seen.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to check if var_x.jpg exists in the view (I'm assuming you can do this). 
If var_x.jpg does not exist, just add it to a dictionary:
"missing_images" of the form {"var_x":"missing","var_y":"missing"} etc
and pass the dictionary to your view
then in the template you just need:

```
{% if missing_images.var_x %} display fallback
{% else %} display var_x.jpg
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking for some tech to check for the existence of a file on certain kind of Django storage backend.